# Uploaded IPA does not appear in iOS 8 Test Flight app. Did they change the procedure?

Tags: ios, itunes, testflight, ipa

Created IPA file like zillions times before, added right devices, uploaded to Testflight, invited users, but...

If I use Safari and log into TestFlight dashboard, I can see the build and I can install it. But if I open TestFlight app on my iPad, all I see is the blank screen. Not even one app appears there.

[image]

Did they change something in the process? Does maybe iOS TestFlight app accepts only Beta builds shared via iTunes?

I'd appreciate someone enlightens me.

Comment: more info with pictures! .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33567577/294884  the system is so stupid now, it's a shame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot shown in your question shows the Apple Testflight app. You'll only see beta versions there that you previously uploaded to iTunes Connect.

You'll find more information on the new (i.e. Apple) procedure here: https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Comment: OMG. So they didn't completely bind the new app with old TF API?! This is so disappointing.

Comment: Why do you mention "apple testflight app". We can still install old testflight app on ios8? I thought Safari is the only way.

Comment: It seems as if the new TestFlight has no connection to the old one. Didn't test the old one since, just wanted to highlight that this is now an Apple thing.