# iOS TestFlight: Internal Tester not receiving invite

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, testflight

I set up a build and add two Internal Testers. Immediately after pressing the "Invite" button I noticed that the checkbox next to my email address was the only one that remained checked. The checkbox next to the second tester was unchecked. So I clicked the checkbox and sent another invite, but the same thing happened. I thought nothing of it, figuring it would become checked when he actually installed and tested the app. But he says he never received an invite. Does anyone know if I'm doing anything wrong?

[image]

Comment: So I still have no idea why it wouldn't let me invite this one person. His Apple ID was not an email address, like the others that worked. I had him create a new Apple ID, one that was an email address, and set his role to "Technical" and I could successfully invite that new user. Weird.

Comment: I've got an app in Apple's TestFlight at the moment, and the process is slow and frustrating. I used "TestFlight" (testflightapp.com) for years, then tried Apple's way with this app. I opted to use http://hockeyapp.net instead.

Comment: hi @RyJ - you should really "Tick" one of these answers, cheers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check your External Testers list. 
You can't have same email/tester exists in both Internal and External testers at the same time. 
And, sometimes it does take a while to receive tester emails from Apple.

Comment: I had this, and I tried deleting the external entry, but it kept reappearing once I selected the user in internal again. Also tried deleting them entirely but they kept reappearing in external!

Comment: @shim maybe try remove users from Users and Roles then add them back again?

Comment: That's what I meant by "deleting them entirely". That worked for a different user in my list, but for some reason not this one.

Comment: @shim for me, after I removed all users from the  list and added them back again, it took a while (hrs?) to receive invitation emails.  So, maybe. give it some time. If it still doesn't work, I'm afraid I have no answer for you, try contact with Apple guys. Best luck.

Comment: @Marku it wasn't my question so I can't accept it. Best I can do is to vote it up which I did.

Comment: oh sorry my mistake :P

Answer (score 11):

Just some minor observations that may help, (Nov 2015)

(*) after turning on internal testing, and/or adding an internal tester, it does **take some time** for that person to get the crazy "CompanyName has invited you to test AppName" email --- maybe an hour.  This is ridiculous, but that seems to be how it is

(*) indeed note that there is a ridiculous "CompanyName has invited you to test AppName" email. Again this is for INTERNAL testing.  you'd think that after you click internal testing, the app would of course just pop-up inside TestFlight.  But no.  **nothing happens until the person (often yourself!) gets that email** and confirms in the email

(*) that person (even yourself) has to use the **hilarious Redeem Code feature**, before it finally appears in TestFlight. Again this is just for the *internal testing*

[image]

What a mess!

Comment: My e-mail doesn't look like the screenshot. It just mentions that the app is ready and that I should open it in TestFlight, but I don't see any app in there. I confirmed that I am using the same AppleID. I wish I had such a hilarious redeem code, then at least I would be able to open my own app.

Comment: note that the screen shot only appears IN A BROWSER once you click on the link in the email. the email would be titled like "CompanyName has invited you to test AppName".  note that if you're not getting the code/etc - it's likely you're already signed on to test that app??  simply log in at itunesconnect.apple.com, and go to the app in question, then go to "TestFlight" then "External" - and look at the users.  it will list everyone, every invite, and every device actually installed so far!

Comment: note that to have it RESEND an invitation, stupidly you have to delete the person, save, and then add the person again, and save.  don't forget the save button!  hope it helps, good luck

Comment: Removing and re-adding as internal tester helped. I got a new e-mail, this time with a button that stated 'Start Testing', a button not present in the previous e-mail when I was invited.

Comment: Great, that's your solution then.  Cheers

Comment: Old redeem email does not work as well. I have to delete myself and add myself again so I can test my own app. Really stupid.

Answer (score 7):

## December 2019 Solution

I got the same issue. Fixed:

1) Under the **TestFlight tab**, click **App Store Connect Users.**

2) Select **Edit** at the top right.

3) Try **removing** a user.

4) Click the **+ icon** next to the word "Testers" at the top.

5) Add the person you just removed.

That should work and send them an email with a link to test.

It should also give you the option to **resend invite** to that person now. I think it's ridiculous that you have to do this, but it worked for me

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: I upload a new build of my app and i got an email "ready to testflight" but when i go to testflight tab i see this Waiting for Review
and I've already added testers but no one received an email invitation, Is it related?

Answer (score 5):

I've found that deleting and recreating the user solves the problem.

1. Make sure the user is not an external tester, if they are remove them from that list.
2. Click on their email address from the page in your screenshot.
3. Click delete that user.
4. Go to Users and roles and click the plus to add a new user.
5. Create the user (possibly with a variation of their email address,
   (e.g. neil+1@company.com, neil+2@company.com, etc..)
6. They will then need to click the verification link in their email.

Comment: Worked for me for one user, but this other one, the user reappears in external when they sign in again for the verification

Comment: I initially thought I needed to add them as External Testers - and had completely forgotten that everyone was in there - your (1) answer here was the first one I found - thank you.

Comment: While it's not a best practice it solved my problem too. The problem is with Apple. They should consider sendin invitation in any case when the developer wants.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you've configured the internal testers and then follow the steps as illustrated in the image.

[image]

**Note:** Once you make a testing version available to internal users then any new build for that version would become available to testers upon uploading to iTunesConnect automatically.

Comment: "Once you make a testing version available to internal users then any new build for that version would become available to testers upon uploading to iTunesConnect automatically." I wish this were true, but that's not what I see. My TestFlight list is empty, even though I open it through the link in the received e-mail.

Comment: NOTE at "2" in the image, you probably want EXTERNAL TESTING, not internal.

Comment: and note Marku's answer **"You can't have same email/tester exists in both Internal and External testers at the same time"**

Comment: I am using Internal Testing indeed. I don't even think iTunes Connect allows you to add a user as both external and internal tester.

Comment: @physicalattractio, that's true in my case. With the mention steps in my post, I don't have to invite for new builds for same version as internal users are automatically getting install invitations.

Answer (score 1):

It is not as clear as the old TestFlight and I think it's still too many unnecessary hoops.  Some quick questions...

Did you add them under "iTunes Connect Users" in Users & Roles? (I assume you did)

Under Users and Roles, did you add them under "TestFlight Beta Testers/Internal"?

After that you should be able to add them on the app.

I also think there is an issue where it will not allow you to add them if they don't have a valid device for the build (i.e. an iPad app and they only have an iPhone).  It appears to be trying to be "helpful" by not showing you invalid devices and instead is just confusing.

G

Comment: `I also think there is an issue where it will not allow you to add them if they don't have a valid device for the build (i.e. an iPad app and they only have an iPhone). It appears to be trying to be "helpful" by not showing you invalid devices and instead is just confusing."` This is not true (anymore?). The user in iTunes Connect does not even need to have any iOS devices; this account is only used for receiving the invite email. The link in that email can subsequently be used by _any_ Apple ID owning an iOS device. The redemption code will be linked back to the user in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

For me, none of the above solutions worked.

So I tried editing the "What to Test" under Test Details section after clicking the build no. and voila all the testers got the testflight email. Wasted hours on this.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the *App Store* account used to *download* the TestFlight app is also important! I have a french and a US App Store accounts. If I download TestFlight from the french store, TestFlight requests my Redeem Code (that can't be resent...)
If I remove TestFlight.app, switch to US *App Store* account, download TestFlight then the app is *automagically* configured and I don't need to enter any redeem code.

Crazy! That's the first time i've seen an have that autoconfigures its default data based on the Store/Account it was downloaded from.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was the internal tester had accepted the invite with a different Apple ID (and email address). Getting them to tap the "Stop Testing" button in TestFlight removed them from the test list.

I was then able to re-add the original tester and voila its working again.